# VBA export certain data from Outlook to Excel running but producing nothing?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

Option Explicit

```
Sub CopyToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim vText As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim rCount As Long
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\Rob\Documents\Excel\Excel.xlsx" 'the path of the workbook

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Process each selected record
 rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    sText = olItem.Body
    vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
     rCount = rCount + 1
    'Check each line of text in the message body
    For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step 1
      If InStr(1, vText(i), "Destination -") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("a" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If


Next i
xlWB.Save
Next olItem
xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
If bXStarted Then
    xlApp.Quit
End If
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code is from online where I tried making it work for myself...

I need to extract Specific Data from emails (over 5000) and produce them on an Excel document. I've never touched VBA before only C#, Javascript & C++.

The code runs, the excel sheet updates to the current Date/time but nothing is produced?

Any help please?

I also get an error "Subscript out of range" for this line:

```
xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the second split delimiter to match the first one. This will take care of the Subscript error

Use this:

```
vItem = Split(vText(i), "Destination -")
```

Comment: Ok, but it did fix the `Subscript out of range`, right? Let's see what else is  wrong. I see an error here `For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step 1` If you want to check the lines bottom up, then step should be -1. Are there multiple lines per email that have "Destination -" in them?